# Proper way to restart HTTP server in Python

Tags: python, http, webserver

I'm writing a HTTP server in Python using the code snippet below. The server works well until some IOError happens causing it to restart. Something is wrong with my restart handling since the server starts up fine but does not accept any requests after that.

Is there anything wrong in this code?

```
#!/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
import json
import config
import time
import socket
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from SocketServer import BaseServer


class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
   def parseArgs(self):
        args = {}
        try:
            config.logging.info(self.path)
            args_list = self.path.split("?")[1].split("&")
            for entry in args_list:
               args[entry.split("=")[0]] = entry.split("=")[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        return args

   def do_GET(self):
      try:
        response = {}
        args = self.parseArgs()
        config.logging.debug("Handle the request")
        self._handle_request(args, response)
        config.logging.debug("Write the header back to the client.")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Content-Type:', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
        self.end_headers()
        config.logging.debug("Finish writing the header and start writing JSON response.")
        json_encoded = json.dumps(response)
        config.logging.debug(json_encoded)
        self.wfile.write(json_encoded)
        config.logging.debug("JSON Response written successfully.")
      except Exception as e:
        config.logging.exception('Exception occurs when writing back the response.')
      return

   def _handle_request(self, args, response):
      try:
        response["sysTime"] = long(round(time.time() * 1000))
        if not "cmd" in args:
           response["message"] = "Error: No command provided."
        else:
           response["message"] = args['cmd']
      except Exception as e:
          response["message"] = "Error: Exception occurs (check logs)."
          config.logging.exception('Exception occurs when handling request.')

   def do_POST(self):
       self.send_response(200)
       self.send_header('Content-type',     'text/html')
       self.end_headers()
       self.wfile.write("Nothing here :( ")

def main():
   while True:
    try:
        httpd = HTTPServer(('', config.listening_port), MyHandler)
        sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
        msg = "Serving HTTP on " + sa[0] + " port " + str(sa[1]) + "..."
        print msg
        config.logging.info(msg)
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down server'
        config.logging.info('^C received, shutting down server')
        httpd.socket.close()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        httpd.shutdown()
        httpd.socket.close()
        print "Error occurs. Retry in 5 seconds"
        config.logging.exception('Exception occurs. Retry in 5 seconds.')
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sorry for missing the module config.

```
import logging

# global variables
listening_port = 9001
logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

One url for running this is `http://localhost:9001/?cmd=some_command`. Just paste that into any browser after the server is started.

**Edit:**

I guess this has something to do with the KVM or the way it is set up on my company machine. As my server is running on a KVM which can only be accessed through ssh, every time I exit ssh session, invoking the url command above (in chrome), wait until chrome notifies not connected, get back to the ssh session, invoking the url command again, the error happened.

I put the debug message between the write response in the do_GET() in `self.send_response(200)`. When the exception happens, this is the trace I got. I guess it has something to do with `sys.stderr.write` inside log_message.

```
11/23/2012 10:58:29 AM - INFO - Handle the request
11/23/2012 10:58:29 AM - INFO - /?cmd=get_info&uid=pp
11/23/2012 10:58:29 AM - INFO - Write the header back to the client.
11/23/2012 10:58:29 AM - ERROR - Exception occurs when writing back the response.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "service.py", line 57, in do_GET
      self.send_response(200)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 385, in send_response
      self.log_request(code)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 422, in log_request
      self.requestline, str(code), str(size))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 458, in log_message
      format%args))
   IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

**EDIT:**

The issue went away when I override the `log_message()` to do nothing. I know this only hides the issue, but at least it works temporarily for me.

Comment: Have you considered using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)? Then you don't have to worry about these kinds of things...

Comment: Or [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).

Comment: Your code works when I try it: the server restarts after 5 seconds and accepts connections again.  But I had to hack at SocketServer.py in order to fake a failure, because I couldn't otherwise get an exception out of serve_forever().  You need to post an example that lets us reproduce the problem first.

Comment: @ArminRigo I edited my post, hopefully I can give you more info.
JonClements and syrion: Currently I have to stick with standard Python as requirements for my project

Comment: Your code still doesn't run.  I had to edit it.  I agree that it's strange that you get IOError there.  But I tried adding "raise IOError" at that place, and the exception is nicely captured: it still doesn't go to the "Error occurs. Retry in 5 seconds" path.  Can you provide a fully stand-alone example?  One that works out of the box (depending on external imports only if they are standard enough) and that allows us to reproduce the error by simply running it.  Don't omit anything; a working example is much better than a truncated one.

Comment: I have put a working example, I tried it myself and also include my temporary solution for this. Thanks @ArminRigo for looking into this.

Answer (score -1):

The sys.stderr writes message to the standard output, usually the shell console where you started the program. So if the shell console gets closed, the sys.stderr.writes will raise IO Error.

So the root cause of the issue is the sys.stderr.write in the log_message() function tries to write a message to the ssh shell console(standard output) where you originally started your python program, so if you keep the ssh session alive, the issue won't happen. But if you exit the original ssh session, the shell console gets closed, then the sys.stderr.write can't write message to the original console,  and then IO error happens.... The log_message usually writes something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2015 20:16:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

So the solution is to run your python script with redirecting the standard output to /dev/null as follows:

```
python your_script.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Holp it helps.